# How to play a video in TVML with specific HTTP header?

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml

I'm writing a tvOS app using TVJS and TVML. But it seems cannot play videos with specific HTTP header.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add header to AVPlayer when you set the AssetURL like that :

```
var headers: [String:String] = ["HeaderKey": "HeaderValue"]
let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset.URLAssetWithURL(url!, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers])
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset)
player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(playerItem)
player.play()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using TVJS. Does that mean I have to call Swift code from JS?

Comment: Hum, I've never used TVML, check in the player Class if you have a similar method to add options / headers